# How to disable CSP in qt webengine?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtwebengine

I'm using QWebEngine with Qt5.9.1.

I want to inject webchannel and user script  into some web page to communicate with my c++ code.

But there's always some alerting:

> "[63092:96096:1015/025540.965:INFO:CONSOLE(438)] "Refused to connect
>   to 'ws://127.0.0.1:12343/' because it violates the following Content
>   Security Policy directive".

And user script cann't execute, too.

I have tried to disable Content Security Policy by:

```cxx
page->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::XSSAuditingEnabled, false);
```

But this didn't work.

How should I disable CSP in qt webengine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

I changed the address from `ws://127.0.0.1:12343/` to `ws://localhost:12343/`. The web channel can connect successfully.

I don't know the reason, but it works.